# subscribe display [Object Object], can't make an *ngIf outside of *ngFor

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-ng-if, subscribe

I created an angular Quiz project, every ID can make quizzes and I want to display every Quiz that a logged user has done. I did it like this.

```
// here I call the user id and the id_category inside Result[], but I can't use it on the html part.
 ngOnInit() {
    this.supabase.authChanges((_, session) => this.session2 = session);
    this.getProfile();
    this.supabaseQuiz.getResult().subscribe((res: Result[]) => {
      let resultIdAns = res
      this.result = resultIdAns
      //here I get the result = [Object, Object]
    })
    
    //passare category id
    this.supabase.profile.then(profile => {
      if(profile.data){
        this.userProfile = profile.data
       
      }else{
        // this.router.navigateByUrl('account/addProfile')
      }
    })

  }
```

this is the html part:
here I try to if the result.id_category with the userID to display only his quiz but this if inside the for destroy all the table!

```
  <nz-table #headerTable [nzData]="result" [nzPageSize]="50" [nzScroll]="{ y: '240px' }">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Category</th>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Correct answers</th>
        <th>Final score</th>
        <th>Action</th>

      </tr>
    </thead>
  
    <tbody>
      
      
      <tr *ngFor="let res of result">
        <div *ngIf="this.userProfile?.id === res.id_profile">
        
        <td>{{ res.categoryTitle }}</td>
        <td>{{ res.date }}</td>
        <td>{{ res.rightAnswer }}</td>
        <td>{{ res.finalScore }}</td>
        
        <button nz-button nzType="primary" success (click)="goToDetail(parameterValue)">Dettagli</button>

        <!--<td>{{ res.json_answer }}</td>-->
        </div>
        
      </tr>
    
    </tbody>
  
  </nz-table>
```

there is way to do another subscribe maybe and get the result id_category outside the for? Thanks

Comment: You are using div inside a tr ... and the button is not inside a td. Well the resulting html is not valid. It depends on the rendering engine our this is displayed. What you should you is ng-container for the *ngFor and the tr for *ngIf and the button should be moved to a td.

Comment: But better would be to filter on server side. It seems you transfer data from other users to the client and only filter in the html? This means if i open the dev tools i can check other users results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1- You can make the filtering of the ids check in the `ts` file using [array.find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) against `res.id_profile` and `userProfile?.id`.

2- You do not need to create a new property named `resultIdAns` since you can assign the `API endpoint response` to the `result` property directly.

3- You cannot make the `*ngIf=""` check outside the `*ngFor=""` because the condition predicate in the `*ngIf=""` depends on the variable named `res` from the outer element which is the container of `*ngFor=""`

4-  Your usage of `this.` keyword in the template inside the `*ngIf=""` is invalid.

5- whenever you want to use structural directive it is better for performance reasons to use `<ng-container *ngIf="" ></ng-container>` or `<ng-container *ngFor="" ></ng-container>`